# Get boolean value from another class in android

Tags: android, class, boolean

I have a connectivity manager checker and I want to use in many classes but I don't know how to call the value of boolean in another class.

```
    public class Online {

        public static boolean isOnline() {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
            }
```

A second class looks like the following

```
public class SbyCD extends ListActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.tit_cs);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_f_all);

        new LoadAll().execute();

    }

    public void onlineee() {
    ...
}

    public class LoadAll extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            ...
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            if (Online.isOnline()) {

                ...
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (!Online.isOnline()) {
                onlineee();
            }

            ...
        }
    }

}
```

I want to get from first the boolean value (true or false) for the second.

Comment: define it as a static method

Comment: What's wrong with `boolean result = new MyConnectivityMgr(this).isOnline()`;

Comment: Either define this function in super or base activity or define static function in utility or constant class.

Comment: Your understanding of Java seems to be very poor, maybe you should have a look at a basic Java course first. Then if you are still not finding the answer, come back and edit the question in a more understandable form ("how to call the value of boolean in another class"...??)

Comment: You mean the true and the false is not a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont u try it with integer? Should work like that:

```
public class Online {

   public static int yon;
   public void isOnline() {

   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()){
      yon = 1;
   }else{
      yon = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an Helper method.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (ni != null && ni.isConnected())      
}
```

and you can call from anywhere like `NameOfClass.isOnline(context)`

Comment: Sorry, but I got an error "context cannot be resolved to a variable" for NameOfClass.isOnline(context) in the second class.

Comment: @Sono how did you call it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might want the Activity to be notified when network connectivity is out.

In this case, you can create an AsyncTask Singleton to check connectivity periodically.

You should define an interface say

```
    public interface OnConnectionOutListener{
        void onOut();
    }
```

and let your Activities implement it

In the AsyncTask Singleton, add an attribute of type OnConnectionOutListener

Upon onCreate in your Activities, get the AsyncTask Singleton and set itself as the listener (Observer pattern)

Then if connectivity out is detected in the task, call back the listener.onOut()

Comment: Nope, I want to check connectivity before the app tries to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Make your method as a static

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context cm) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

write this Logic whenever you want know your connection status.

```
if(NameOfYourClass.isOnline(NameOfYourClass.this)){
  //here do what do you want to do
}
```

Comment: It has two errors. Duplicate local variable "cm" and context cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

do this way:

declare **Listener interface** eg.:

```
public interface OnConnectionOutListener {
    /**  notifies Activity when network connectivity is out. */
    void onOut(); 
}
```

implement it in your **SkyCD class**:

```
public class SbyCD extends ListActivity implements OnConnectionOutListener {
...

    //our listener implementation after we detect that connection is out
    @Override
    public void onOut() {
        // ups... we are not connected do some stuff then
    }
...
}
```

then in **AsyncTask class**:

1. declare **Listener**,
2. declare **context**
3. override **onPreExecute**
4. add method to check connection eg. **isOnline()**

as below:

```
class LoadAll extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    //listener 
    private OnConnectionOutListener connectionOut;   

    //context declaration 
    private Activity _context

    //constructor
    public LoadAll(Activity _context) {
        this._context = _context;
        this.connectionOut = (OnConnectionOutListener) _context;
    }

    //override method on Task pre execution
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (!isOnline()) {
                connectionOut.onOut();
            } 
    }    

    //implementation of connection checking 
    //where **_context** is context passed to your non Activity class LoadAll
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = 
          (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
          return true;
        } else return false;
    }
```

fire your task as thread somwhere in your **SkyCD class** passing context

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        ....  =  new LoadAll(this).execute(args);

    }
}).start();
```